# Exporting coordinates of shapefile into CSV using FME?

Tags: shapefile, csv, fme-form

I use FME to make a series of transformations from an autocad file to a shapefile (with line geometry).

What I am trying to do is to also export (together with the shapefile) a CSV file containing the coordinates.  More specifically I need to get only the first and last coordinate of each linestring in the shapefile.

How can I do this in FME 2014?

Right now I have managed to export only a CSV containing the attribute values corresponding to each line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option its to make use of 2 coordinateExtractors , 1 for index 0 (1st coordinate) and another with index -1 (last coordinate) .
[image][image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I later export the coordinates to a CSV file in a way to have xi,yi,xf,yf?

Comment: In FME2014 open up the Feature Type dialog and manually edit the attribute names. In 2015.0 you could just set the feature type to automatic and connect it up.